# DBIx::Class: Only select results where has_many greater than zero

Tags: mysql, perl, orm, dbix-class

In our MySQL database, I have a `third_party_accounts` table and it `has_many` `third_party_campaigns`. However, not all accounts will have campaigns. What I would like to do in `DBIx::Class` is select only those accounts which have one or more campaigns. The simplest was I've found is as follows:

```
my $third_party_account_rs = $schema->resultset('ThirdPartyAccount');
my $with_campaigns_rs      = $third_party_account_rs->search(
    { third_party_account_id => \'IS NOT NULL' },
    {
        join     => 'third_party_campaigns',
        group_by => 'me.id',                                                                                                                                 
    }
);
```

For the relevant database columns:

```
mysql> select id from third_party_accounts;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, third_party_account_id from third_party_campaigns;
+----+------------------------+
| id | third_party_account_id |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 |                      1 |
|  2 |                      2 |
|  3 |                      1 |
+----+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This seems like such an obvious use case that I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $with_campaigns_rs = 
    $schema->resultset('ThirdPartyCampaigns')
    ->search_related('third_party_account');
```

Comment: This has already been suggested to me, but it doesn't work. Note that in my original query I had `group_by => "me.id"`. That prevents duplicate `ThirdPartyAccount` records. This "reverse" solution, with the data I have above, will leave me with *two* `ThirdPartyAccount` objects with an id of 1.

Comment: To avoid dupliate returns add `{ distinct => 1 }` to the `->search_related` call.